# Magento Override Existing Source Model

Tags: magento

I want to add one more option in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Source_Backorders`.How do I override this source model?

Is overriding similar to Entity model override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The xpath is `global/models/cataloginventory/rewrite/source_backorders`. Depending on your sorting needs/preference, simply `array_merge()`, `array_unshift()`, or `array_splice()` your option where it needs to go in the overridden `toOptionArray()` method.

Comment: Can you explain how to do the same for magento 2? I am trying to override Magento\Fedex\Model\Source\Generic through preference

Comment: That’s a separate question and should be asked as such.

Comment: I have already asked the question here -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219998/magento-2-how-to-override-a-source-model .

Comment: That’s all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

just try to put same folder in your local folder like this
magentodemo\app\code\local\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Backorders.php and now write the code you want to add in Backorders.php and then check it out.

Comment: The practice you describe is not appropriate given the framework's rewrite capacity. Given the simplicity of the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Source_Backorders` class it is not a monumental concern, but for many other models it woud be.